# Docker commands hanging with no response

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

Docker daemon is running fine, but docker just hangs indefinitely with no output when I do `docker images`, `docker ps` and so on. This wasn't happening last night and it's driving me nuts.

I reinstalled docker on my AWS Linux AMI with no luck. I have also tried `sudo service docker restart` and that didn't yield a fix. If anyone has run into this or has any suggestions please share.

Instance Info:

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2016.09"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2016.09"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2016.09:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"
Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.09
```

Docker version:

```
Docker version 1.11.2, build b9f10c9/1.11.2
```

Comment: most probably it is hanging on a system call, you can use `strace -f docker ps` and see where it is hanging. This can give an indication on what is going wrong.

Comment: @MIE what should I look out for when running that command? How can I identify the hang?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old, but to fix this, try deleting the contents of:

```
/var/run/docker/libcontainerd
```

Comment: Perfect! Saved lot of hours!!

Comment: Was a reboot necessary after doing this?

Comment: No, but hopefully you're not still waiting for an answer :)

Comment: on my machine I found `/var/run/docker/containerd` are both same?

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining exactly what it is we are deleting.

Comment: I didn't have that folder (/var/run/docker) (Big Sur, Docker 3.0.1) but temporarily remove the files /var/run/docker-cli.sock and /var/run/docker.sock solved it for me (deleting and undeleting them)

Answer (score 5):

https://forums.docker.com/t/what-to-do-when-all-docker-commands-hang/28103/4
By korayhk:

You don’t need to reinstall or delete the container image data. Simply do below :

Stop the service first

```
sudo service docker stop
```

Clean up some of the files as mentioned in above post from Sam.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker
sudo rm /var/run/docker.*"
```

Start service now

```
sudo service docker start
```

Start your docker image

```
docker start <container-name>
```

You will receive an error when you run the docker run at first try:

Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container with id exists: 7a244b8f5d07081538042ff64aebfe11fac1a36731526e77be53db7d94dca44d\n"
Error: failed to start containers:

Try running docker start command again. You will have your container up and running magically without any errors.

Comment: Additionally, you may have to unmount netns. [`umount /var/run/docker/netns/default` - see medium.com article](https://medium.com/@BillMetangmo/resolve-docker-netns-issue-device-or-resource-busy-3a235d2ee013)

Comment: Also be wary of deleting the docker.socket file with `sudo rm /var/run/docker.*` especially, if you use something like Portainer. There is a race condition between the daemon and the api that allows Portainer (and others) to recreate the socket as a directory instead of a socket: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30348

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Tried all advices listed here. Reinstalled docker several times, removed different folders.

The interesting thing is that commands works fine under a root:

```
sudo docker version
```

So I decided that it can be related to a local settings of my linux account. Renaming or removing folder ~/.docker helped me.

The folder contained some `docker context` related settings. Maybe a remote context was set.

Comment: For me it was a remote context that was not reachable without VPN. As soon as the VPN is disconnected not even `docker --help` works!

Comment: .. and I just realized this only happens if the problematic remote context is set as default.

Answer (score 1):

After updating my ubuntu to **5.8.0-34-generic**. I had similar issue. after various attempts to resolve it, My final solution was to downgrade docker to the previous working version. Steps as below:

1. Kill docker

> ```
> root@LT01:~# killall dockerd
> root@LT01:~# ps -aux | grep dockerd
> root@LT01:~# kill -9 your docker pid
> ```

2. Remove docker ce, cli and container.io

> ```
> root@LT01:/home/xyz# apt remove docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
> ```

2. optional step: my dockerd was constantly restarting so I had to disable ir. If you do the same. you'll need to enable it after new installation:

> ```
> systemctl disable docker
> ```

3. check previous versions:

> ```
> root@LT01:/home/xyz# apt-cache madison docker-ce
> ```

4. install older version from the above list, in my case, docker-ce *5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal*:

> ```
> root@LT01:/home/xyz# apt install docker-ce=5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal
> ```

5. optional: if you need downgrade containerd.io and cli as well then:

> ```
> apt install docker-ce=5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal containerd.io=1.3.9-1 docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-focal
> ```

6. check your installation:

> ```
> whereis docker
>
> systemctl status docker
> ```

Also, marked my docker to not upgrade on *apt upgrade* command.

Comment: I had the same issue on Fedora with the new update, had to downgrade to docker-ce-3:19.03.13-3.fc32.x86_64

Answer (score 1):

I tried both of the answers by Garreth and steamfood, but didn't want to reinstall docker as Invincible suggested. I hadn't changed anything on my system so figured the problem had to be with my configuration/container setup rather than an installation problem with docker itself.

When running `systemctl start docker` or anything else to start or stop the docker service, I was getting this in my logs (running `systemctl status docker` in another terminal):

`Loading containers: start.`

`Container ef06fbb157169332c453f503bb2543ce914daf54600f8fa44699fa5833d9eb90 failed to exit`

It would hang after this point.

To fix this, I first killed the process identified in `systemctl status docker` with `sudo kill -9 $PID`.

I then deleted everything in `/var/lib/docker/containers` with `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/*`.

This cleared out the problematic container and everything worked from then on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue caused where the  child processes are still running or these parent process is monitoring its child process.

- Check if you have defunct processes -> `ps -ef | grep defunct`
- Now those process need to be killed -> `kill -9 PID PPID`
- Then refresh or restart the terminal. This solved the issue for me.

Also check -> https://dev.to/jeden/killing-a-defunct-process-7od

Comment: can you fix the typo - grept

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old, but it was pretty much the only thing showing up for me. It took me quite a while to find what was happening for me.

I was using **Loki** as the Docker logger. There was a connectivity issue and the logs could no longer be written. This lead to all docker commands hanging and me being unable to even restart the service.

My solution:

`pkill docker` to kill all docker processes

remove loki from `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

`rm -R /var/lib/docker/`

`service docker restart`

Afterward I recreated my containers. Be aware that just restarting the containers is not sufficient.